# user_cancel_reassign() doesn't work when user has more than 10 nodes

Tags: nodes

I am attempting to delete users with no permissions/roles from our sites. The user's node should be kept.

This code works when the user has a few nodes. On deletion, their ownership is passed to the anonymous user.

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;
use \Drupal\user\Entity\User;
    
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables, $hook) {    
  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  $user = \Drupal::currentUser();    
  if (count($user->getRoles()) == 1 && ($route_name != "system.401" && $route_name != "user.login")) {
    $userWithoutRole = User::load($user->id());
    if ($userWithoutRole !== NULL) {
      user_cancel([], $user->id(), 'user_cancel_reassign');
      $userWithoutRole->delete();
    }
    throw new UnauthorizedHttpException('insufficient permissions');
  }
}
```

It doesn't work when the user is the author of more than 10 nodes. All the nodes are deleted when the user is deleted.

Another method is invoked, I suppose.

How can I solve this?

The same issue is present with the *Auto purge users* module.

Answer (score 2):

[`user_cancel()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_cancel/8.9.x) is run in a batch. This means that either it's called in a form, or [`batch_process()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/function/batch_process/8.9.x) needs to be called after it. For example, this is the code used by [`UserController::confirmCancel()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Controller%21UserController.php/function/UserController%3A%3AconfirmCancel/8.9.x).

```php
$edit = [
  'user_cancel_notify' => isset($account_data['cancel_notify']) ? $account_data['cancel_notify'] : $this->config('user.settings')->get('notify.status_canceled'),
];
user_cancel($edit, $user->id(), $account_data['cancel_method']);

// Since user_cancel() is not invoked via Form API, batch processing
// needs to be invoked manually and should redirect to the front page
// after completion.
return batch_process('<front>');
```

It's not necessary to delete the account, as that is already done from [`_user_cancel()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/_user_cancel/8.9.x), the batch operation callback used from `user_cancel()`.

```php
case 'user_cancel_reassign':
case 'user_cancel_delete':
  // Send account canceled notification if option was checked.
  if (!empty($edit['user_cancel_notify'])) {
    _user_mail_notify('status_canceled', $account);
  }
  $account->delete();
  // …
```

It's also probable that `hook_preprocess_page()` is the wrong place to call `user_cancel()` as it would be called when the page is being rendered, while the batch operations require to redirect users. See [`batch_process()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/function/batch_process/8.9.x), which contains the following code.

```php
if (($function = $batch['redirect_callback']) && function_exists($function)) {
  $function($batch_url->toString(), [
    'query' => $query_options,
  ]);
}
else {
  return new RedirectResponse($batch_url->setAbsolute()->toString(TRUE)->getGeneratedUrl());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but ...Adding batch_process(); has no effect on my code. If Removing   $userWithoutRole->delete(); in my code the user is not deleted. If not hook_preprocess_page(), where ? for what i am trying to achieve ?

Comment: If the account isn't deleted that means that batch operations are not correctly executed. I would rather use a controller associated to a route, to be sure they are correctly executed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was performing mass user deletion in a Drush command. First I was calling directly the batch operation `_user_cancel` because calling `user_cancel()` was leading to perform a batch in a batch, which would not work.
But the problem was that because of that I was skipping some actions of `user_cancel()`, like for example the call of `hook_user_cancel()` of any other module implementing the hook in question.

Finally I was able to call `user_cancel()` :

```
protected function cancelUsers() {
  $user_settings = \Drupal::config('user.settings');

  foreach ($this->obsoleteUser as $uid) {
    $cancel_method = $user_settings->get('cancel_method');

    $edit = [
      // Use $user_settings->get('notify.status_canceled') in
      // the following if you need to apply the user settings.
      'user_cancel_notify' => FALSE,
      'user_cancel_method' => $cancel_method,
    ];

    // user_cancel() will set batch operations itself. All is needed is a call
    // to process it.
    user_cancel($edit, $uid, $cancel_method);
  }
}
```

And make sure in my command that I was using the batch initiated by `user_cancel()` :

```
$batch =& batch_get();

if (empty($batch)) {
  return;
}

drush_backend_batch_process();
```